# mongoose doesn't resolve queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa, co

I'm struggling to understand what's wrong with the following queries. I'm using the mongoose 4.1.10 and mongodb 3.0.6.

```
passport.use("local-signup", new passportLocal.Strategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password'
    //passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
}, (username, password, done) => {
    co(function *() {
        try {
            const user = yield User.findOne({ "local.email": username });

            if (user) {
                return done(null, false);
            }
            else {
                const newUser = new User();

                newUser.local.email = username;
                yield newUser.save();
            }
        }
        catch(ex) {
            done(ex);
        }
    }).then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

More specifically `User.findOne({ "local.email": username });` never resolves.

I have even tried to use the callback approach but again I don't get any results.

Comment: is `done` defined somewhere else? you should return value from generator or throw an error

Comment: Look at the updated question. Actually, you're not right; I'm yielding values from generator. You don't have to explicitly have a return statement. In fact, you should omit returning values. It's better using `yield` for that

Comment: I'm not sure you want to be calling `done()` from your `then()`.  It seems the code as is, will sometimes call `done()` twice.  Once from within the generator and then again from the then()

Comment: What's the function `co` you're calling from the start of your anonymous function?

Comment: I see, should have actually looked up the 'co' library before commenting...

Answer (score 0):

`User.findOne({ "local.email": username })` returns a Query, you need to call `.exec()` to return a Promise, more info in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec).